# How can we separate equation smaller separated equation in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Hello I am new to Python and Sympy. i have created small project That working like sympy gamma but i want to separate my equation in to smaller sub parts.is it possible using sympy function.
I am Attaching one image for more information about my Problem.

[image: 1]]

It is my views.py file

```py
def index(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        x = symbols('x')
        init_printing(use_unicode=True)
        # transformations = (standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,))

        transformations = standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,) + (convert_xor,)  #covert_xor used
        equ =  latex(request.POST['equ'])
        eq = parse_expr(request.POST['equ'], transformations=transformations)                  #request.POST['equ'].replace("^", "**")
        sympifyy = latex(sympify(eq, evaluate=True))

        sympifyy1 = sympify(eq)
        sympifyy2 = latex(simplify(eq))
        derivative = latex(sp.diff(eq,x))
        integration = latex(sp.integrate(eq, x))
        # integration = integrate(eq, x)
        # pretty(latex(Integral(eq, x)),use_unicode=False)
        # print(pretty(Integral(sqrt(1/x), x), use_unicode=False))
        rootss = solve(eq)
        limits = limit(eq, x, 0)        
        seriess = latex(series(eq, x, 0, 10))

        data = {
            'Sympify' : sympifyy,
            # 'Equation formate' :    aa formate |exsin(x) + excos(x) dx mate use karva nu in future
             'Equation formate' :equ,
            'Sympify1' : sympifyy1,
            'Sympify2' : sympifyy2,
            'Derivative' :  derivative ,
            'Integration' : integration,                 #   "\int "+ latex(eq)+": "+
            'Roots' : rootss,
            'Limit' : limits,
            'Series' : seriess
            }

        return render(request, 'index.html', {'data':data})

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

This is my Ouyput:[image: This my Output and i want split or separate the Equation]What to do? Any suggestions please.

Comment: Please show the code that you wrote to generate what you're showing.

Comment: @ dirkgroten  check it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split a sum into terms with/without a given symbol you can do

```
>>> i, d = (x + x*y + 2).as_independent(x, as_Add=True); (i, d)
(2, x*y + x)
```

To split an expression into terms:

```
>>> Add.make_args(d)
(x, x*y)
```

To split a product into factors with/without a given symbol you can do

```
>>> (2*x*y).as_independent(x)
(2*y, x)
```

See also "See Also" references in the docstrings of these methods.

Comment: but it is a dynamic. so i can't know wich symbol is come from user side and i am work on web not on console. so what i can do for that? and i am spilt that Eq. in two symbols that symbol i used for next step. is there any idea? what i do?

Comment: You can find out what symbols an expression uses with `expr.free_symbols`